# HTML5 geolocation is not accurate

Tags: html, google-maps, geolocation

I was using the following code to get my current location. But the longitude and latitude generated was not at all accurate. It was showing a location about 700 Kms away from my location. How can I make it accurate?

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I have good coordinates but the accuracy was 500+, I went outside and it's better, <10 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could try a different geocoding provider.

There are lots to choose from:

- https://smartystreets.com
- http://geocoder.us
- http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/

Disclaimer: I'm a developer at SmartyStreets.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be asking about looking up addresses. They want to use GPS to get their lat/long.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not using GPS. If you aren't, then `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` returns a position based on your ISP

Comment: So, Is there a way to use GPS?

Comment: If your device supports it, you only have to enable it (like in mobile phones); if you are using a PC or something else that is not equipped with GPS you can use gpsgate  or something similar