# Unable to get Accurate coordinates using HTML5 geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I need to get the accurate latitude and longitude of user.I tried using by setting enableHighAccuracy to true,But the accuracy is about 960903 meters.I have checked it in chrome.Don't have an idea where it is going wrong.I am posting the code and output below.I hope someone can help me.Thank You:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lattitude and longitude</title>


        <script>
        var options = {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
          timeout: 5000,
          maximumAge: 0
        };

        function success(pos) {
          var crd = pos.coords;

          console.log('Your current position is:');
          console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
          console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
          console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
        }

        function error(err) {
          console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
        }
         function getlocation(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
         }

         </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Displaying location using Latitude and Longitude</p>
        <button onclick="getlocation()">Click</button>

    </body>

</html>
```

```
Output:
 Your current position is:
 Latitude : 15.912899800000002
 Longitude: 79.7399875
 More or less 960903 meters.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 geolocation is not accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048125/html5-geolocation-is-not-accurate)

Comment: Thank You.I have checked but it didn't solved my issue.